# How to remove the specific class, starts with "color" in jquery

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I want remove class, starts with "color". the classes are added dynamically i didn't know many class starts with color.

```
<div id="sample" class="color1 orange color2 color3 blue"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#sample").removeClass("[class^='color']");
```

But it doesn't work. Any Help?

Answer (score 10):

Loop over all the classes and test if they begin with `color`.

```
var classes = $("#sample").attr("class").split(' ');
$.each(classes, function(i, c) {
    if (c.indexOf("color") == 0) {
        $("#sample").removeClass(c);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work here

```
$('div')[0].className = $('div')[0].className.replace(/\bcolor.*?\b/g, '');
```

OR

```
 $('div').attr('class',$('div').attr('class').replace(/\bcolor.*?\b/g, ''));
```

Basically here I am getting each word in `classes` & replacing anything which starts with `color`.

Comment: Nice solution, but a bit of an explanation would be nice.

Comment: Maybe not an issue for this poster, but it won't work for `class="color-blue"` because `\b` will stop at the `-`.

Comment: As it's a jQuery question, why not use `attr('class')?`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Conversely, what's wrong with using `className`? You skip the overhead of `attr()`, and available `className` is available in all browsers.

Comment: @Matt: `[0].className` is less robust than `.attr('class')` (from a maintenance perspective) and attr() requires no knowledge of the DOM element properties. Just a suggestion. Feel free to use raw JS all you wish :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie added that also, but I don't know what is better.

Comment: `$('div').attr('class',$('div').attr('class').replace(/\bcolor.*?\b/g, ''));` would do... no need for the function as you are only processing one element

Comment: In both cases you should it is preferred to only run the selector once (and use a temp variable for the jQuery element) or better yet use the version of attr that takes a function (which will then work on multiple elements - see following) :)

Comment: @Matt: You certainly can't do this with the DOM property: `$('div').attr('class', function (i, attr) {return attr.replace(/\bcolor.*?\b/g, '');
});` This will operate independently on *each matching element* so will handle multiples properly. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'), function (el) { el.className = el.className.replace(/\bcolor.*?\b/g, ''); });`

Comment: @Matt... OK, you *can* do it with DOM (if you are willing to over-complicate the code to prove a point) :) RemoveClass actually takes a function as well. So I still say jQuery is cleaner than raw JS (IMHO). :)